# Determine design-time context of a custom winforms control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

Suppose I have a custom WinForms control:

```
public class MyBaseControl : Control
{
     ...
}
```

which is extended like:

```
public class MyControl : MyBaseControl
{
     ...
}
```

By checking the `this.DesignMode` property flag it is fairly trivial to determine whether or not the control is being visually designed, however **is there a way to determine if the `MyControl` itself is being designed, versus being manipulated on a from at design time?**

---

To provide additional clarification, within the `MyControl` class, I am trying to differentiate between design-time when the component itself is being designed:

[image: "Control" designer]

and when the component is added to a form from the toolbox at design-time:

[image]

Comment: Someone had asked for clarification, added screenshots to more clearly show what it is that I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for clarification :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the control is root in designer or not.
You can get the [`IDesignerHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.idesignerhost(v=vs.110).aspx) service and then check the [`RootComponent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.idesignerhost.rootcomponent(v=vs.110).aspx) property to see if your control is the root component for current designer or not.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
public partial class MyBaseControl : UserControl
{
    public MyBaseControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool IsRootDesigner
    {
        get
        {
            var host = (IDesignerHost)this.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
            if (host != null)
                return host.RootComponent == this;

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is precisely what I was after.  Thank-you.